# Синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствует операнд после оператора "транспорту"

Tags: c#

Выбивает ошибку в коде:

`dvLocality.RowFilter = "Тип транспорту LIKE '%" + TransComboBox.Text + "%'";`

Я понимаю, что это из-за того, что я так назвал столбец, но мне необходимо именно название "Тип транспорту".

Comment: dvLocality.RowFilter = "[Тип транспорту] LIKE '%" + TransComboBox.Text + "%'"; //mssql

Comment: [Expression Syntax](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=net-6.0#expression-syntax)

Comment: использовать экранирование обязательно при сложном задании названия столбцов(пробелы, кириллица, спец. символы и прочие нестандартные ситуации)

Comment: @Konst спасибо большое, вы мне очень помогли